# remove \n after "lines.replace"

Tags: python

Executing the script with the space after "conv:" the results is a "newline" as below:

```
    lines = lines.replace("www.","conv: ")

conv:
yahoo.com
conv:
yahoo.it
conv:
yahoo.org
conv:
yahoo.net
```

how remove \n (new line)?

removing the space character after conv: the script runs perfectly.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open('/home/user/tmp/prefix.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    lines = lines.replace("http://","")
    lines = lines.replace("www.","conv:")

    urls = [url.split('/')[0] for url in lines.split()]
    print ('\n'.join(urls))
```

results is:

```
conv:yahoo.com
conv:yahoo.it
conv:yahoo.org
conv:yahoo.net
```

I'd like have:

```
conv: yahoo.com
conv: yahoo.it
conv: yahoo.org
conv: yahoo.net
```

Comment: what is the output using replace with the space on it? what about using rstrip()? like `lines = lines.replace("www.","conv: ".rstrip())`

Comment: hello, same output results

Comment: i don't get the question then, what is the expected output?

Comment: Try `urls = [url.split('/')[0] for url in lines.split('\n')]`

Comment: @MarcoRimoldi You dont need your list comprehension to get your desired output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
urls = [url.split('/')[0] for url in lines.split()]
```

splits your lines on a space, so you'll get the `conv:` part as a single url.

You could do

```
urls = [url.split('/')[0].replace("conv:", "conv: ") for url in lines.split()]
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

You dont even need the list comprehension:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open('/home/user/tmp/prefix.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    lines = lines.replace("http://","")
    lines = lines.replace("www.","conv: ")

    print lines
```

Comment: @MarcoRimoldi if you do it this way you will be saving yourself an unnecessary list comp

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to accomplish your goal from your given code would be to change

```
urls = [url.split('/')[0] for url in lines.split()]
```

to

```
urls = [url.split('/')[0] for url in lines.split('\n')]
```

Thus you will be splitting the `lines` string on the newlines, rather than on all whitespace.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you joining prints with \n while at this point you will have something like urls= ['conv: ', 'yahoo.com'] .so print (''.join(urls)) will work- print will go to next line itself , (don't know input file assuming one url per line)